# NSTableView delegate not being called when connect to a dedicated controller

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

To be able to customize some of my NSTableview's behaviour, I created this new class to act as a controller for the table view.

```
@interface aTableViewController : NSObject<NSTableViewDelegate>

@end
@implementation aTableViewController    
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex
{
    return @"something";
}

- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView willDisplayCell:(id)aCell forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex
{}

@end
```

The existing table view is binded to an NSArrayController to get data, works beautifully. I used an NSObject to reference to this aTableViewController in the IB, and connect the table view's delegate to this controller object. However, none of these delegates ever got called.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by " I used an NSObject to reference to this aTableViewController in the IB"?  Did you drag out a blue cube and change its class to aTableViewController?

Comment: @rdelmar yes, that's exactly what I did.

Answer (score 3):

> My NSTableview is view-based instead of cellbased. That's why tableView:willDisplayCell:forTableColumn:row: never gets called

For view-based tableview, you can use

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see several problems with what you posted.  In the @interface code you have aTableViewController, whereas in your @implementation code you have WorkspaceTableViewController.  Is one of these a typo or is this 2 different classes?

Secondly, the methods you have in the controller are data source methods not delegate methods. If you are using bindings to populate your table, then these methods aren't called.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo and I just corrected it. tableView:willDisplayCell:forTableColumn:row: is a delegate method but it was never called either...

Comment: @RobertKang, sorry, I missed that one, you're right, that one is a delegate method, but you have nothing in that one.  Try putting a log statement in there and see if it's called.  I copied your code into a project, and that one was called.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did put an NSLog in it, but it doesn't get called either. I checked again, the tableViewController was properly initialized in and connected as a delegate to the tableview. And if I just set the delegate to the viewController itself, the delegate methods in viewController works fine with no issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "set the delegate to the viewController itself"?  Isn't that what you said you did in the first place? What did you change to get it to work?

Comment: ugh, there is a viewController and a tableViewController. the tableview resides in a view which belongs to the viewController. Sorry if this confuses you. It only works when I connect the tableView's delegate to the viewController(aka the file's owner in IB)

Comment: I have tried the same approach with an empty project. It still doesn't work. I think I must have missed something here...

Comment: Starting with an empty project and a dedicated tableViewController. I connected both delegate and dataSource of the tableView to the tableViewController. The dataSource delegate was called, but the delegate method(tableView:willDisplayCell:forTableColumn:row:) was not. This is confusing...

Comment: I think I find the issue. My NSTableview is view-based instead of cellbased. That's why tableView:willDisplayCell:forTableColumn:row: never gets called.... Thanks for your help!